# How to save data from HTML to excel, on click on "submit" button of form?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

```
<form>
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want onclick "submit" it should save first name and last name in Excel sheet. I don't want to use database and I don't have any server. I read somewhere that we can do the same in CSV. Help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: No... I am not sure whether  we can do so or not... And if we can do, then how... I am new to it.

Comment: See this link. http://www.databison.com/html-to-excel-using-javascript-and-excel-to-html-using-vba/

Comment: Maybe [this](http://excelbuilderjs.com/cookbook/addingDataToAWorksheet.html) will get you started

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is to create an html table. You can set the form values into an invisible table and simulate the download of html table with a link. Excel reads the html and display the data.

---

Example :

```js
function exportF() {
  //Format your table with form data
  document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var html = table.outerHTML;

  var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + escape(html); // Set your html table into url 
  var link = document.getElementById("downloadLink");
  link.setAttribute("href", url);
  link.setAttribute("download", "export.xls"); // Choose the file name
  link.click(); // Download your excel file   
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return exportF()">
  <input id="text" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<table id="table" style="display: none">
  <tr>
    <td id="input">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<a style="display: none" id="downloadLink"></a>
```

Comment: I worked for me. But how i can add one more row in excel sheet.

Comment: @user2842328 Add a line in your HTML table with `tr` tag

Answer (score 0):

There are various libraries that allow the generation of `.xlsx` files, you will need to pick one of them (Google `xlsx.js`), read out the values in the form on submit and then create the spreadsheet you wish using the library you picked.